# .net mvc search page with partial view and different models

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a search page. The main page will display the search results with a sidebar that contains the search menu controls, rendered as a partial view. Both the main view and partial view will have different view models. See code below, which is generating the following error:

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SearchResultsViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SearchMenuViewModel'`

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model SearchResultsViewModel

<div class="sidebar">     
    @Html.Partial("_SearchMenu", Model)
    @{Html.RenderAction("SearchMenu", "Search");}
</div>

<div class="results">
@foreach(var result in searchResults)
{
    //display search results
}
</div>
```

**_SearchMenu.cshtml**

```
@model SearchMenuViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    //Search parameter controls
}
```

**SearchController**

```
public ActionResult SearchMenu()
{
    var model = _searchRepository.GetSearchMenu();
    return PartialView("_SearchMenu", model);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _searchRepository.GetSearchResults();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I think your method  _searchRepository.GetSearchMenu(); returns SearchResultsViewModel rather than SearchMenuViewModel

Comment: See the section of the dupe titled _Passing the wrong model from a view to a partial view_ (your `SearchResultsViewModel` needs to contain a property that is typeof `SearchMenuViewModel`, and you pass that property to the partial)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke. My problem was indeed with my models, the `SearchMenuViewModel` was not a property of `SearchResultsViewModel`.